# How to make symlink executable?

Tags: symlink

I am using the Cloud9.io IDE.

I have downloaded the Julia generic executable and extracted it.

```
sudo wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.0/julia-1.0.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar xvzf julia-1.0.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

now I can run the program by `julia-1.0.3/bin/julia`.

So the next step I try to make a symlink so I just run the program by entering `julia`. So I tried

`sudo ln -s julia-1.0.3/bin/julia julia`

and when I run `julia` it says

> bash: julia: command not found

But the file is clearly in my directory. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash will find an executable specified by its bare filename (i.e. without preceding path elements) only if it is on its search path, which is stored in the PATH variable. The current directory is not necessarily on the search path.

To see the current search path, try this:

```
echo $PATH
```

To see if a command is on your search path, try this:

```
which command
```

If `command` is on the search path, the `which` command will return the command's location on the file system. - To extend your search path with the directory of your command, try:

```
PATH=$PATH:directory_to_be_added
```

Note that `directory_to_be_added` should be the full directory name to the executable (not a directory relative to your current directory).

Once the directory of your `julia` command has been added to your PATH, `which julia` should return `julia`'s full pathname, and `julia` should be executable from anywhere on your filesystem.

Changing the PATH is a general way of ensuring that executables that you use regularly are found by the shell. If you merely wish to run a command that is not on the search path once (i.e. in a one-off attempt), or you wish to override the search path, you can specify your command including pathname elements. So, to run a command that is in the current directory and not on the search path (or not the first command with that name on the search path), you could use `./command`.

Comment: How come `julia-1.0.3/bin/julia` works? So `bash` can run a executable if you specify the full path?

Comment: @xiaodai The PATH is consulted only in case the `command` that your trying to execute has no path-elements in it. So you could run `julia` from the current directory by giving the command `./julia` (the `./` being the path element that prevents a PATH search). Similarly, your command `julia-1.0.3/bin/julia` includes path elements, which causes Bash not to search the PATH, but instead to run the specified executable directly.

Comment: I'd recommend putting the part about `./julia` in your answer — that's the normal thing people do.

Comment: @mattdm You are right. I amended the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

Answering to the question asked in the title.

Nothing is required to make a symlink executable (or not executable for that matter).

Actually, a symlink permissions serve no purpose on most OSes, including Linux. The execution permissions that are taken into account are the ones of the file linked to, if any.